# Overlay headline over video using CSS

Tags: html, css

Whats the best way to make a fine grid overlay as shown in the picture?

(It is laying over a video background. But behind the Headline.)

[image: fine grid]

Comment: Lay png over video but under headline. Use z-index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Kristine, you can have 3 layers:

1. Video
2. Fine grid (png for example, due to it's transparency)
3. Heading (Gramercypark)

You can achieve this by using `z-index` in your css.
[More info & example here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

For the image I would recommend using a + figure, and put it on repeat to cover the whole page. Using just a small image on repeat will minimize the (down)loading time and bandwidth of your website.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this trick:

```css
.pattern { position:relative; background:url(https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/m0ynovs4hafceboer3zr.gif); width:636px; height:358px; text-align:center; color:#fff;}
.pattern:after { content:""; width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:0;}
.pattern > div { position:relative; z-index:1;}
.pattern:after{ background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAABhJREFUeNpiYGBgePz//38GRhABAgABBgBFTAbfCBNE2AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==); /*background:url(images/pattern.png);*/}
```

```html
<div class="pattern">
  <div>
    <h1>Windows 10</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```